# JMeter CSV file does not loop through sequentially

Tags: jmeter

My Jmeter script is taking all the values from CSV but when I see it in the HTTP request output, they are not been displayed sequentially.  For e,g- 50th row in CSV does not correspond to 50th HTTP request.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you running on single thread or using any thread group? because if you are using thread group then your each http request will be process by different thread so there might be a chance that one thread receive response and logged it before other thread.

Comment: thread group, 50+users

Comment: That is why your output has response out of order and that can be ignored and if you want to maintain the order then run on single thread but it will take to much time to complete and not suggested for any performance test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fine when you have more than 1 thread and all threads are sharing the same CSV file.

Each thread executes the test plan independently - but share the same csv file. these threads do not wait for each other. Ex: Thread 3 does not have to wait for thread 2 to pick the second row.  It is like first come and first serve! Whichever thread is ready to pick the data - it gets the data from csv. Rest assured all the csv rows will be read sequentially ie..not random rows.

[image]